# Rails, searchkick (Elasticsearch 2.3) completion suggester error

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm using a legacy ES 2.3 and searchkick 2.5 versions in an app.

A custom mapping is defined in a model.

```
mappings: {
  my_model: {
    properties: { 
      ...
      suggestion: { type: "completion", analyzer: "ru_RU", search_analyzer: "ru_RU" }
    }
  }
}

def search_data
  {
    ...
    suggestion: suggestions
  }
end

# a custom method on the model to fill suggestions
def suggestions
 ['some', 'suggestions'] # an array 
end
```

When I'm trying to reindex the model I get `Mixing up field types: class org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.StringFieldMapper$StringFieldType != class org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.CompletionFieldMapper$CompletionFieldType on field suggestion` error.

What am I doing wrong?
Would really appreciate any help with solving this issue.

Comment: solved by upgrading ES version to 2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by upgrading ES version to 2.4